# Skip train journey

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, lufthansa

I have a Luftansa return flight (Dubai-Munich).
First leg flight is Dubai-Frankfurt and then a train journey from Frankfurt-Munich.
Can I skip this train journey to Munich as I want to stay back in Frankfurt for tourism and I will go to Munich a day later. Is there a way for Airline to know that I skipped the train journey? Will it affect my return leg? (Return journey I will travel as normal)

Comment: Do you mean that Lufthansa sold you a train ticket from Frankfurt to Munich?

Comment: It's probably https://www.lufthansa.com/ie/en/rail-and-fly

Comment: @hilmar there is also an airrail or whatever it is called now service where the rail part is considered a "flight" (with connection protection etc.) which technically can't be skipped and if it's for the outgoing journey has to be checked in (online) in advance. But if you insist that you were on the train Lufthansa can't really check (at least a few years ago). For Swiss's SBB connections there are zero problem with skipping, but I'm not sure how DB controls work now.

Comment: If it’s ‘rail & fly’, the website says “Your Rail&Fly ticket is valid on the day of your flight as well as one day before departure and one day after your arrival in Germany”, so your plan would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way for Airline to know that I skipped the train journey?

Highly unlikely. German trains don't have a formal check-in process that captures all passengers. You just hop on the train at your departure location and present your ticket if a conductor comes by to check. Sometimes there is no conductor and there is no ticket check.

Comment: The rail and fly ticket may be valid for first class where ticket inspection is very likely.